# Retrofit 2 check call URL

Tags: android, http, retrofit, retrofit2

Is there any possibility to compare a `Call` URL with a `String` in `Retrofit 2`?

For example we can take this `baseUrl`:

```
https://www.google.com
```

And this `Call`:

```
public interface ExampleService {
    @GET("dummy/{examplePartialUrl}/")
    Call<JsonObject> exampleList(@Path("examplePartialUrl") String examplePartialUrl;
}
```

with this request:

```
Call<JsonObject> mCall = dummyService.exampleList("partialDummy")
```

There's a way to obtain `https://www.google.com/dummy/partialDummy` or also `dummy/partialDummy` before getting the response from the call?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Assuming you're using OkHttp alongside Retrofit, you could do something like:

`dummyService.exampleList("partialDummy").request().url().toString()`

which according to the OkHttp docs should print:

`https://www.google.com/dummy/partialDummy`

Comment: Thanks very much, I also edited the answer adding ".url()" to return only url in string format.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you explain, how we can Achive same thing while using RxJava ?? Because in that case, return type will be Observable so how to get request() and url ??

Comment: What if we are using Retrofit 2 with RxJava 2?

Answer (score 7):

```
Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: ConfigurationListener::"+call.request().url());
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I found another way to accomplish this by using retrofit 2 and RxJava

First you need to create an OkHttpClient object

```
private OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient()
{
    //this is the part where you will see all the logs of retrofit requests 
    //and responses
    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    return new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .connectTimeout(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .readTimeout(500,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(logging)
            .build();
}
```

after creating this object, the next step is just use it in retrofit builder

```
public Retrofit provideRetrofit(OkHttpClient client, GsonConverterFactory convertorFactory,RxJava2CallAdapterFactory adapterFactory)
{
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(mBaseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(convertorFactory)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(adapterFactory)
            .client(client)
            .build();
}
```

one of the attributes you can assign to Retrofit builder is the client, set the client to the client from the first function.

After running this code you could search for **OkHttp** tag in the logcat and you will see the requests and responses you made.