# Firebase performance network only showing agregated request

Tags: firebase, firebase-performance

I'm with a problem with Firebase Performance Network.

I added the default performance monitoring on my android app but in the performance network console on Firebase its showing the detail for the agregated request. ex: `api.test.com.br/*`

[image]

My app make many requests for differents endpoints with the same base url.
But I would like to see the detail for each endpoint separately.

I'm using Retrofit2 with okhttp3.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48332073/how-can-i-get-the-url-and-method-of-retrofit-request-on-onsubscribe-of-rxjava-2

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Performance Monitoring now supports creating custom URL patterns that allow you to target more specific URLs. From the docs:

> You can create custom URL patterns to monitor specific URL patterns
>   that Firebase isn't capturing with its derived automatic URL pattern
>   matching. For example, you can use a custom URL pattern to
>   troubleshoot a specific URL or to monitor a specific set of URLs over
>   time.

So if you did want to capture something like `api.myAppName.in/app/v3/user/*/profile/**`, you would now be able to

See [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/https_traces#custom-url-patterns) for more details: