# Get final request URL without executing the request in Retrofit2/OkHttp3

Tags: android, retrofit2, picasso, okhttp

In my project, I have a `Retrofit2` interface to define the URLs of some images on a server. I also have an `OkHttp3` client which has a couple of interceptors.

Is there a way to get the full URL of one of those image (after the execution of the interceptors) so I can pass it to `Picasso`? I didn't find any method in `Picasso` that takes a `Call` directly.

Comment: I don't know if I get what you want. Does your network call return the URLs? If so, you need to call `execute` or `enqueue` and pass the result (image URL) to Picasso.

Comment: you can add interceptor to get url and pass it to picasso.

Comment: @Héctor I want to get the URL that would be called by `execute` or `enqueue`, without having to call them, and with the interceptor applied. @Rahul Kumar can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

**Have you tried?**

`call.request().url()` where `call` is type of `retrofit2.Call`

**Alternatively**

Let's say you have the following retrofit interface:

```
public interface ExampleService {
    @GET("dummy/{examplePartialUrl}/")
    Call<JsonObject> exampleList(@Path("examplePartialUrl") String examplePartialUrl;
}
```

With a call request:

```
Call<JsonObject> mCall = dummyService.exampleList("partialDummy")
```

To get the full URL use:

```
dummyService.exampleList("partialDummy").request().url().toString()
```

Source: [Retrofit 2 check call URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36532273/retrofit-2-check-call-url)

Comment: That's already what I am doing, but interceptors are not applied. I have some interceptors that add query parameters to every requests, but those are not called with this solution.