# How to get an original address from retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I have a response from retrofit request to "`/address/{id}/data`" link on my server, where id - query param. When I'm getting response from retrofit, I have link with already pasted param "`/address/001/data`". How can I get original link without query in Retrofit (`/address/{id}/data`)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrofit 2 check call URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36532273/retrofit-2-check-call-url)

Answer (score 2):

**What you can do**

You may have some other options, but you can start with this

**Option 1**

You can directly access the url from the response returned by retrofit using

```
response.raw().request().url()
```

This returns the http url of the request, eg. prints out

```
okhttp/example-request D: //http://example.com/address/001/data
```

**Option 2**

Another is by adding network requests interceptor with the help of [okhttp-logging-inceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor).

```
val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
logging.level = Level.BASIC
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(logging)
    .build()
```

The option 2 is way better than option 1 since it will be intercepting all the network request in your application without re-doing so much work on each request callback. Also, optionally you can customize the logging level of it and add it only on a specified condition.

Eg. Default log on DEBUG mode

```
val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger.DEFAULT)
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    logging.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY // setting the level
    client.addInterceptor(okHttpLoggingInterceptor) // adding interceptor
}
```

**References**

- https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor

Comment: Hi Strangelove, does the answer helped you?